# Acts As Taggable On gem rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I cannot get the Act_as_taggable gem to work. I have followed several tutorials and even viewed the out of date Railscast on this issue but my main problem in with the method tag_list, I am using Rails 4

I have done the following:

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4' (bundled)
rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations (rake db:migrate; restart server)
Added acts_as_taggable to my Blog.rb 
Passed tag_list through safe params in BlogsController
Placed this into my _form partial:

```
        <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
        </div>
```

When I go to edit a Blog post the tags are not separated by commas even though when I submitted the form I placed commas after each tag. In rails console I have verified that tag_list is not a method because I keep getting the error

```
      undefined method `tag_list' for #<Class:0x007fa668cb03e8>
```

And therefore I haven't been able to add Tags to any Blog post yet. Please help

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I'm using Rails 4 but and the gem version is 3.5.0.

---

I'm having some issues with the same gem and this is what I've done.

```
class Common < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  acts_as_taggable
  # ...
end
```

In the controller:

```
class CommonsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def my_params
    params.require(:common).permit(
      # ...
      :tag_list,
      # ...
    )
  end
  #...
end
```

And in the template:

```
<%= form_for @common do |f| %>
  <!-- ... -->
  <p>
    <%= f.label :tag_list %> <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </p>
  <!-- ... -->
<% end %>
```

This worked for me, but:

- When I write a list of tags separated by comma, they are saved correctly. For example: "red, green, blue".
- But, when the form is loaded again, the commas disappeared from the text field, like in "red green blue". If I save the form again then a new tag is created: "red green blue".

If I create a virtual attribute in the model it works, but I think that breaks the normal behavior of the tag_list method in the gem:

```
class Common < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  acts_as_taggable
  # ...
  def tag_list
    tags.join(', ')
  end
end
```

Hope this helps you in any way...

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. The commas don't persist when you get back to editing the form. Have you been able to find a lasting solution?

I used your solution and redefined "tag_list". it works. So far I don't see anything it breaks. But if there's a better solution, please share

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you add this lines on Model

```
acts_as_taggable # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills
```

use your model object in form

```
@blog.tag_list_on(:skills_tags)
```

Comment: I thought I don't need acts_as_taggable_on  if i just want tags, the acts_as_taggable_on :skills isnt that for specific type of tag rather than a generic type of tag

Comment: can you please look at this link its describe many option https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: I have read it but am not sure as to how to set up tag_list. I havent been able to add tags to my app and am having trouble following the doc